# Beautifying a countup timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am trying to recreate a Javascript timer I saw on this website: http://www.everysecond.io/apple/

Specifically the

```
**"It has been 1 minute and 32 seconds"**
```

I have a normal counter but it displays like a digital clock, I've been googling for an hour now and have no luck finding a solution.

Here is a pen with the counter from that website, I was trying to learn from it and strip it down to just what I need but with no luck. http://codepen.io/LukeD1uk/pen/ZOwvqv

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   var sec =0, min=0, hour=0;
setInterval(function(){
   sec++;
   if(sec==60){sec=0; min++;}
   if(min==60){min=0; hour++;}
   var str = 'it has been';
   str+= hour?' ' +hour + (hour==1?' hour':' hours'):'';
   str+= min?(hour?' and ':' ') +min+ (min==1?' minute':' minutes') :'';
   str+= sec?(min||hour?' and ':' ') +sec+ (sec==1?' second':' seconds'):'';
document.getElementById('passed').innerHTML=str;
},1000);
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/1t00ac9z/2)

Comment: Briliant :D Thank you

Comment: It had an error. I corrected it. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `setInterval()` can drift slightly after multiple calls. Not sure if it is a requirement here, but if you need an accurate timer, it would be safer to use a reference time.

For instance:

```js
var start = +new Date();

setInterval(function() {
  var d = Math.round((+new Date() - start) / 1000),
      n, res = [];

  [[3600, 'hour'], [60, 'minute'], [1, 'second']].forEach(function(e) {
    if(n = (d / e[0]) | 0) {
      res.push(n + ' ' + e[1] + (n > 1 ? 's' : ''));
      d -= n * e[0];
    }
  });
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'It has been ' + res.join(' and ');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```